# C# scoping operator

Tags: c#, scope, curly-braces

back in school, we wrote a compiler where curly braces had the default behavior of executing all expressions, and returning the last value... so you could write something like:

```
int foo = { printf("bar"); 1 };
```

Is there something equivalent in C#?  For instance, if I want to write a lambda function that has a side effect.

The point less being about the lambda side effect (just an example), more if there is this functionality... for instance in lisp, you have [progn](http://www.rattlesnake.com/intro/progn.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In principle, the answer from Vlad is correct and you don't need to declare the lambda function as a delegate in advance.

Except, the situation is not as simple in C#, because the compiler cannot decide whether the syntactical lambda expression should be compiled as a delegate (e.g. `Func<int>`) or an expression tree (e.g. `Expression<Func<int>>`) and also, it can be any other compatible delegate type. So, you need to create the delegate:

```
int foo = new Func<int>(() => { 
  Console.WriteLine("bar"); return 1; })();
```

You can simplify the code slightly by defining a method that simply returns the delegate and then calling the method - the C# compiler will infer the delegate type automatically:

```
static Func<R> Scope<R>(Func<R> f) { return f; }

// Compiler automatically compiles lambda function
// as delegate and infers the type arguments of 'Scope'
int foo = Scope(() => { Console.WriteLine("bar"); return 1; })();
```

I agree that this is an ugly trick that shouldn't be used :-), but it is an interesting fact that it can be done!

Answer (score 7):

There's nothing stopping you from having side-effects in a lambda expression.

```
Func<int> expr = () =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("bar");
    return 1;
};
int foo = expr();
```

Answer (score 5):

```
int foo = (() => { printf("bar"); return 1; })();
```

---

Edit: thanks for the constructive critique, it ought to be

```
int i = ((Func<int>)(() => { printf("bar"); return 1; }))();
```

Comment: This is the right answer -- that said, seriously consider not doing this.

Comment: You folks might want to actually check whether the code compiles before voting up.  This doesn't.  -1.

Comment: Yes, yes, `printf` doesn't exist in C#. But the answer is not about that.

Comment: Why does it not? It looks as if it could compile at first glance.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the lack of a `printf` function.  Change it to `Console.WriteLine` and you'll still get a compile error, "Method name expected".

Comment: May be overly verbose, but how about `int foo = ((Func<int>)(() => { Console.WriteLine("bar"); return 1; }))();` which should compile?

Comment: The answer is to illustrate how the things can be done. It doesn't contain class declaration, too. It doesn't contain `main` method, etc. etc. etc. Do you need that all?

Comment: @Vlad: No, you don't need all that for a post on SO.  You do need valid syntax.  This is not valid syntax.

Comment: Vlad, it won't work even with a class declaration and `main` method.

Comment: @jball: Yes, that syntax does work, because of the explicit cast to a delegate.  Not easy on the eyes, but it compiles.

Comment: @Aaronaught & @jball: good catch -- and yet another reason why nobody should ever do this.

Answer (score 3):

We've considered making even-more-brief syntaxes than `()=>{M();}` for definition of a lambda, but haven't managed to actually find a syntax that both reads nicely and is not easily confused with blocks, collection/object initializers, or array initializers.  You're stuck with lambda syntax for now.

Answer (score 2):

You're talking about an anonymous function: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882516.aspx, I think.